# vim: delete all words on line except last

Tags: vim, replace

I'm having trouble coming up with a vim find/replace to delete all the words on a line except the last one, i.e. in a bit of SQL, it be nice to generate a list of all the aliases from a bunch of code

```
select 
column_a alias_a,
column_b alias_b,
column_c alias_c

from 
...
```

I'd like to just generate the list

```
alias_a, alias_b, alias_c
```

So I think i want to delete all words that aren't immediately followed by a comma and line ending

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**option 1**:

```
%s/\v.*\s(\S+)$/\1/
```

**option 2**: 
using macro

```
qa$T d0jq
```

then `x@a` x is how many lines you want to apply this macro

**option 3**

turn to external command:

```
:%!awk '$0=$NF'
```

**option 4**: 
if you have Align or similar plugin, align those lines right, then use `c-v` block select and remove, just leave the last column.

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
:%s/.* \(.*\)\n/\1 /
```

Comment: Won't that grab the comma at the end as well?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Yes, that seemed to be what the OP was asking for.

Comment: That's not how I read it, but I can see what you mean. Please ignore my comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

```
:%s/\v(.*\s)(\w\+)/\2/
```

Which means to grab everything until the last space into capture group 1, everything afterward into capture group 2, and replace it with just capture group 2.

Replaces this:

```
select 
column_a blah blah blah alias_a,
column_b foo foo foo alias_b,
column_c bar bar bar alias_c

from
```

To:

```
select 
alias_a,
alias_b,
alias_c

from
```

You can then punch `Shift-J` a few times to get the aliases into one comma separated line.

Comment: I'm seeing "pattern not found: \v(.*\s)(\w\+)

Comment: Hmm, I typed exactly that into my vim and it worked for me, I'm not sure what might be different in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Visually select the lines then execute the following

```
:norm $bd0
:*j
```

Note: `:norm` will show up as `:'<,'>`

For more help see:

```
:h :norm
:h :j
```